# Save Word Doc as 2003 XML with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, save

I'm working in Word 2010.  If I do a save as, I can save down to Word XML 2003.  However, I cannot find this option as a parameter for SaveAS under VBA. I've looked on MSDN and Google, but no luck.

The best that I found was this page, but it doesn't say if any of these options are the Word XML 2003 option.

[WdSaveFormat Enumerations from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat)

Does anyone know what parameter to use to save to Word 2003 XML?  If someone has a good link to a VBA reference or book recommendation that would also be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
wdSaveFormat.wdFormatXML
```

Comment consolidation:

You can tell it is 2003 XML format by looking at the resulting XML. Two things mark it as being Word 2003 XML format

- the Namespace for all the w: tags is
  xmlns:w="schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml
- there is no  structure as there is in the Word 2007 Flat
  OPC format.

You may, however, see some namespaces and elements that were not used in the Word 2003 XML as saved by Word 2003.

---

The OP asked about the origin of this information.

The response was (lightly edited)

Primarily experiment+the fact that word2007 and later uses the Flat OPC XML format.

I haven't looked closely at the differences between word 2003 XML as produced by word 2003 and versions produced by word 2007 etc. but when I glanced, there seemed to be namespaces later than 2003 and some post-2003 attributes (mainly related to compatibility, I think).

I don't know of any post-2003 docs. for the 2003 format, or any official schematic for the pkg:package namespace. That suggests that the ZIP format .docx/m/dotx/m format is the only format with formal recognition.

Comment: Does that save to 2003 XML format or 2010 format? How do you know?

Comment: Thanks for this.  Answer accepted! Do you know this from experience or is there documentation somewhere?